# Excel VBA: Opening Workbooks and Copying Cells

Tags: vba, excel

The macro below opens a series of workbooks from a list, then copies some data from them. It works fine for the first workbook, then crashes on the second. I've tried changing the order, and it's always the second workbook that causes it to crash.

```
Sub ImportData()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastSumRow As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    For k = 2 To lastRow
        k = 2
        lastUsedRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(k, 2).Value <> "Imported" Then
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Analysis\" & Cells(k, 1), UpdateLinks:=False
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Activate
            For j = 3 To 100
                If j Mod 3 = 0 Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells((j / 3) + lastUsedRow, 1).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(j, 1).Value
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells((j / 3) + lastUsedRow, 2).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(j + 1, 2).Value
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells((j / 3) + lastUsedRow, 3).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(j + 1, 3).Value
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells((j / 3) + lastUsedRow, 4).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(j + 1, 4).Value
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells((j / 3) + lastUsedRow, 5).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(j + 2, 2).Value
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells((j / 3) + lastUsedRow, 6).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(j + 2, 3).Value
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells((j / 3) + lastUsedRow, 7).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(j + 2, 4).Value
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells((j / 3) + lastUsedRow, 8).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(j + 1, 5).Value
                End If
            Next j
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
        End If
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setup").Cells(k, 2).Value = "Imported"
    Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you set `k = 2` inside a `For k` loop?   As far as I can see, this shouldn't "crash".  It should process the first workbook, then just go into an infinite loop.

Comment: Ha. Thank you. That was a remnant of when I was debugging it earlier. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your error is here:

> ```
> Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Analysis\" & Cells(k, 1), UpdateLinks:=False
>                                                  'Ooops     ^^^^^
> ```

The `.Activate` and `.Select` calls are convoluted enough that I'm not really going to expend the effort figuring out what *should* be the active worksheet at that particular point in your code on the second run through the loop.  Whatever it is, it's different than it was when you started and an unqualified call to `Cells` implicitly refers to whatever worksheet is the `ActiveSheet` at the time.  This builds a bad file name (or fails completely) and then the wheels come off.

The best thing to do is not use the `Active*` objects at all.  Get references to the objects that you're using, and well, use them.  That way there is no chance that you'll get wires crossed.  While you're at it, you can give them names that make it obvious what you're working with at a glance.

Couple other things before we get to the code that doesn't use `Activate` and `Select`.

---

`lastSumRow` is never used and `lastUsedRow` is never declared.  I'm assuming they were supposed to be the same thing.  You should put `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules to avoid this type of error (and worse ones).

---

These 2 lines of code make very little sense together:

> ```
>         For j = 3 To 100
>             If j Mod 3 = 0 Then
> ```

If you only want to copy every 3rd row, skip all the division and just increment your loop counter with a `Step` of 3:

```
        For j = 3 To 99 Step 3
```

Note that you can stop at 99, because `100 Mod 3` is never going to be `0`.

---

Your `With` block here isn't using the captured reference...

> ```
> With ActiveSheet
>     lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row
> End With
> ```

...but you continually use this pattern that would be *useful* in a `With` block:

> ```
> ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells((j / 3) + lastUsedRow, 1).Value = ...
> ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells((j / 3) + lastUsedRow, 2).Value = ...
> ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells((j / 3) + lastUsedRow, 3).Value = ...
> ```

---

Hard-coding `Cells(1048576, 1)` will fail on older versions of Excel. You should use Rows.Count instead.

---

As mentioned in the comments, `k = 2` creates an infinite loop.

---

You don't need to repeatedly find the last row of the sheet you're copying to with this code:

> ```
> lastUsedRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row
> ```

Each time you go through your "`j`" loop, the last row increases by one.  Just add 1 to `lastUsedRow` instead of doing all the row counting gymnastics.

---

If you're working with `Worksheets`, use the `Worksheets` collection instead of the `Sheets` collection:

> ```
> ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")   '<--I could return a Chart!
> ```

---

Put all of that together, and you come up with something like the code below.  Note that I have no clue what the `ActiveSheet` is supposed to be when you start this macro, so I just named the variable it's stored in `active`. It's quite possible that it's one of the other worksheets it grabs a reference too (I have no clue) - if so, you should consolidate them into one reference:

```
Public Sub ImportData()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastUsedRow As Long
    Dim dataRow As Long
    Dim fileNameRow As Long

    Dim active As Worksheet
    Set active = ActiveSheet
    With active
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Dim setupSheet As Worksheet
    Set setupSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Setup")
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
        lastUsedRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For fileNameRow = 2 To lastRow
            If active.Cells(fileNameRow, 2).Value <> "Imported" Then
                Dim source As Workbook
                Set source = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Analysis\" & _
                                            active.Cells(fileNameRow, 1), False)
                Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
                Set dataSheet = source.Worksheets("Summary")
                For dataRow = 3 To 99 Step 3
                    .Cells(lastUsedRow, 1).Value = dataSheet.Cells(dataRow, 1).Value
                    .Cells(lastUsedRow, 2).Value = dataSheet.Cells(dataRow + 1, 2).Value
                    .Cells(lastUsedRow, 3).Value = dataSheet.Cells(dataRow + 1, 3).Value
                    .Cells(lastUsedRow, 4).Value = dataSheet.Cells(dataRow + 1, 4).Value
                    .Cells(lastUsedRow, 5).Value = dataSheet.Cells(dataRow + 2, 2).Value
                    .Cells(lastUsedRow, 6).Value = dataSheet.Cells(dataRow + 2, 3).Value
                    .Cells(lastUsedRow, 7).Value = dataSheet.Cells(dataRow + 2, 4).Value
                    .Cells(lastUsedRow, 8).Value = dataSheet.Cells(dataRow + 1, 5).Value
                    lastUsedRow = lastUsedRow + 1
                Next
                source.Close
            End If
            setupSheet.Cells(fileNameRow, 2).Value = "Imported"
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```